# Не могу создать словарь при парсинге через BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Приветствую.

Нахожусь на начальной стадии изучения Питона.

Загрузил в BeautifulSoup сайт-жертву.

Код, который меня интересует:

```
<li class="cinema-city">
<div class="city-caption">
        Кривой Рог</div>
<ul class="cinemas-list">
<li class="cinema" data-alias="kinoodessa-kr-rog">
<a href="/cinema/kinoodessa-kr-rog">Одессакино СРК Union</a></li>
<li class="cinema" data-alias="mx-krivrog-victory">
<a href="/cinema/mx-krivrog-victory">Мультиплекс в ТРЦ «Виктори Плаза»</a></li>
<li class="cinema" data-alias="olymp">
<a href="/cinema/olymp">Олимп</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="cinema-city">
<div class="city-caption">
        Луцк</div>
<ul class="cinemas-list">
<li class="cinema" data-alias="premiercity">
<a href="/cinema/premiercity">PREMIER CITY</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="cinema-city">
<div class="city-caption">
        Львов</div>
<ul class="cinemas-list">
<li class="cinema" data-alias="kp-dovjenko">
<a href="/cinema/kp-dovjenko">Кинопалац им. Довженко</a></li>
<li class="cinema" data-alias="kp-kopernik">
<a href="/cinema/kp-kopernik">Кинопалац Коперник</a></li>
<li class="cinema" data-alias="kp-lvov">
<a href="/cinema/kp-lvov">Кинопалац</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Не знаю, как правильно сопоставить "кинотеатр" с "городом" в цикле, чтоб вытянуть из тегов все нужные значения. Я потом это все хочу запихнуть в БД.

Правильно ли я предполагаю?, что мне для каждого кинотеатра нужно будет создавать словарь вида:

`cinema1 = {"city":"<city>", "cinema_name":"<cinema_name>", "href":"<href>"}
cinema2 = {"city":"<city>", "cinema_name":"<cinema_name>", "href":"<href>"}`

У меня вытянуть отдельно города и отдельно кинотеатры получается, но потом нельзя из них сделать правильный словарь, так как теряется привязка город-кинотеатр.

Благодарю.

Едит:
Изначально, пытался начать как то так:

```
city = soup.find_all(class_="city-caption")
cinema = soup.find_all(class_="cinema")

for keys in city:
    for values in cinema:
        print(keys, "=>", values)
```

но понял что не то. Я не знаю, как сделать так, чтоб "кинотеатр" понимал, что в html коде он вложен в "город".

Comment: код, который вы написали, приложите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BS это плохой выбор для сложных задач. Используй lxml. Код будет примерно такой:

```
for city in etree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
    print city.xpath("text()")[0] # city
    for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a")
       print cinema.xpath("text()")[0] # Name
       print cinema.xpath("@href")[0] # url
```

Comment: я рассматривал lxml как вариант, но документация показалась сильно заумной по сравнению с BS.

Comment: С самой библиотекой lxml связаны будут ровно 3 строчки:<br/>
`from lxml.html import fromstring`<br/>
`etree = fromstring(response.text)`<br/>
`etree.make_links_absolute(response.url)`<br/>
всё остальное -  это [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), как этим пользоваться - смотри [здесь](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/), не сложнее той отсебятины, которая используется в BS, но является стандартом для разбора XML и позволяет сделать всё что только придёт в голову.  
P.S. [бонус](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114772/)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы решить данную задачу, ее необходимо декомпозировать на более простые. Скажем, сначала Вам нужно всего лишь достать всю информацию о каждом городе. Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
soup.select('li.cinema-city')
```

У каждого города есть название, которое можно вытащить из первого `div` тега с классом `city-caption`:

```
city.find('div', class_='city-caption').text.strip()
```

Далее, у каждого города есть список кинотеатров:

```
city.select('a')
```

Из которого можно достать url:

```
cinema['href']
```

И название:

```
cinema.text.strip()
```

Вам осталось всего лишь скомбинировать эти методы. Я Вам также рекомндую разбить все это дело по разным функциям.

Comment: спасибо большое за внимание к моей проблеме. Если вытягивать все по отдельности, отдельными функциями, как вы предложили, то теряется связь город-кинотеатр. Вот это у меня главная проблема. Я не знаю, как вытянуть данные сохранив связь город-кинотеатр. Уже сутки ищу решение в инете, не могу найти. Как я понимаю проблему, нужно написать цикл, что при вытягивании кинотеатра будет идти проверка, к какому городу он относится и в итоге вывести список город1-кинотеатр1-ссылка1, город1-кинотеатр2-ссылка2, город1-кинотеатр3-ссылка3, город2-кинотеатр1-кино_ссылка1, город2-кинотеатр2-к_с2 и тд.

Comment: Связь город - кинотеатр не теряется. Никто не мешает вытянуть все города и для каждого города вызвать функцию, которая будет вытягивать кинотеатры из этого города.

Comment: О таком подходе не думал. Попробую. Подскажите пожалуйста еще с 1 нубским вопросом. Я начал пробовать то, что вы предложили выше. city.find('div', class_='city-caption').text.strip() - что нужно присвоить city? Я пробовал сделать так city = soup.select('li.cinema-city'), но в итоге получается AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: `select` возвращает список городов, соответственно, `cities = soup.select('li.cinema-city')`. Далее либо вы итерируете по этому списку с помощью цикла, либо используете функцию `map`.